# Hadoop: Conflict in JPS and hdfs admin report for checking the number of available data nodes

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, bigdata

I am working on a five node hadoop multinode cluster. After setting up the clusers, I used JPS command to check whether all of the nodes are properly connected/not. Following were the results after running JPS command in one master node and all the other four slave nodes respectively.

**master node**

```
8825 SecondaryNameNode
8647 DataNode
9105 NodeManager
9418 Jps
8493 NameNode
8971 ResourceManager
```

**slave nodes**

```
1816 NodeManager
1711 DataNode
2154 Jps
```

But when I tried checking from the command **hdfs dfsadmin -report**, I got the following result:

```
Configured Capacity: 242317230080 (225.68 GB)
Present Capacity: 224333357056 (208.93 GB)
DFS Remaining: 224333332480 (208.93 GB)
DFS Used: 24576 (24 KB)
DFS Used%: 0.00%
Under replicated blocks: 0
Blocks with corrupt replicas: 0
Missing blocks: 0

-------------------------------------------------
Datanodes available: 1 (1 total, 0 dead)

Live datanodes:
Name: 127.0.0.1:50010 (localhost)
Hostname: localhost
Decommission Status : Normal
Configured Capacity: 242317230080 (225.68 GB)
DFS Used: 24576 (24 KB)
Non DFS Used: 17983873024 (16.75 GB)
DFS Remaining: 224333332480 (208.93 GB)
DFS Used%: 0.00%
DFS Remaining%: 92.58%
Configured Cache Capacity: 0 (0 B)
Cache Used: 0 (0 B)
Cache Remaining: 0 (0 B)
Cache Used%: 100.00%
Cache Remaining%: 0.00%
```

I am unable to understand as to why the **Data nodes available** is shown as 1 in the above report. Also, my program is running very slow and so I guess only of the datanodes is active. Kindly mention the cause behind this anomaly.

Comment: Where you executed the hdfs dfsadmin -report command in master or slave ?

Comment: Check the logs in all of the servers for clues. Jps only shows that those processes are running but it doesn't claim anything about their connectivity.

Comment: @MarHserus: In master node. In slave node I am getting " Call From re3el/127.0.0.1 to master:54310 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; " error message. How can I fix this?

Comment: @LauriPeltonen: I have observed that 127.0.0.1 is listening to the ports in netstat but not the external IP address. Also as mentioned in other posts I already removed 127.0.1.1 line in the /etc/hosts file. Kindly suggest an alternative

Comment: Can you ssh between the servers without password? Have you added all the servers in `hosts` files, with their computer names? (I personally have the same `hosts` file on all my servers)

Comment: @LauriPeltonen: yeah. I can ssh between the servers without password.